# This JavaScript doesn't work in Opera

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I use this function in my website. http://jsfiddle.net/Alkasih/kn2695r7/

It works fine in Mozila, but in Opera, it doesn't seem to work. Can anybody help me how to make it works in any browser. Because it may be a big deal for the website.

```js
var currentDiv = 0;
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#pilihWarna option").click(function(){
    $(".bigandsmall").eq($(this).index()).css( "display", "block" );

    if($(this).index()!=currentDiv){
      $(".bigandsmall").eq(currentDiv).css("display","none");}
    currentDiv=$(this).index();

  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="pilihWarna" name="fgdfd" style="background:none;">
  <option>satu</option>
  <option>dua</option>
  <option>tiga</option>
  <option>empat</option>
</select>    

<div class="something">
  <div class="bigandsmall">
    <p>satu</p><img src="image/Chrysanthemum.jpg" width="50px" /></div>

  <div class="bigandsmall">
    <p>dua</p><img src="image/Desert.jpg"  width="50px"/></div>

  <div class="bigandsmall">
    <p>tiga</p><img src="image/Hydrangeas.jpg"  width="50px"/></div>

  <div class="bigandsmall">
    <p>empat</p><img src="image/Jellyfish.jpg"  width="50px"/></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Which version(s) of Opera? It makes a big difference, Opera 12 isn't all that closely related to Opera 25, for instance, they use different layout, rendering, and JavaScript engines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you want something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/kn2695r7/1/).

```
$("#pilihWarna").change(function () {
    $(".bigandsmall").hide().eq($("#pilihWarna")[0].selectedIndex).show();
});
```

Use `change`, useful when a user navigates with keyboard anyway. And use `selectedIndex` to get the index of the selected option.

Comment: While you *can* relate them by index (as the OP did), it's fragile.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Only seems fragile if his HTML differs. But since he used it in his OP, I presume he is aware of that.

Comment: Right, that's what I mean by fragile. It makes it easy to mess up during maintenance.

Comment: Anyway, what does OP mean. I prefer this because this solution doesn't need much identity since I will use a php looping.

Comment: @alisa "OP" stands for "original post", or "original poster". Similarly there are the acronyms TS (topic starter) and TC (topic creator). It refers to the person who asked the question.

Answer (score 2):

The `click` event on `option` elements isn't all that cross-browser reliable (for instance, your code doesn't work on Chrome, either, and probably not on Safari). Instead, I'd use `change` and `click` on the `select`, and handle showing/hiding the content based on the currnetly-selected value(s) in the `select`.

Here's *one possible* way to do that:

Add `id="satu"` and such to the `.bigandsmall` divs, then:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#pilihWarna").change(function() {
    var current = "#" + $(this).val();     // Get the value of the select as an ID selector
    $(".bigandsmall").not(current).hide(); // Hide all .bigandsmall that don't match
    $(current).show();                     // Show the one that does
  });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#pilihWarna").change(function() {
    var current = "#" + $(this).val();
    $(".bigandsmall").not(current).hide();
    $(current).show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="pilihWarna" name="fgdfd" style="background:none;">
  <option>satu</option>
  <option>dua</option>
  <option>tiga</option>
  <option>empat</option>
</select>    

<div class="something">
  <div id="satu" class="bigandsmall">
    <p>satu</p><img src="image/Chrysanthemum.jpg" width="50px" /></div>

  <div id="dua" class="bigandsmall">
    <p>dua</p><img src="image/Desert.jpg"  width="50px"/></div>

  <div id="tiga" class="bigandsmall">
    <p>tiga</p><img src="image/Hydrangeas.jpg"  width="50px"/></div>

  <div id="empat" class="bigandsmall">
    <p>empat</p><img src="image/Jellyfish.jpg"  width="50px"/></div>
</div>
```

The `option` elements have an implicit value based on their text, so I used that as the `id` on the elements to show/hide.

---

Alternately, you don't *have* to use an `id` (sometimes it's best not to), you could use a `data-*` attribute instead (`data-key="satu"`, perhaps):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#pilihWarna").change(function() {
    var current = '[data-key="' + $(this).val() + '"]'; // Get the current value of the select as a `data-key` selector
    $(".bigandsmall").not(current).hide();              // Hide all .bigandsmall that don't match
    $(current).show();                                  // Show the one that does
  });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#pilihWarna").change(function() {
    var current = '[data-key="' + $(this).val() + '"]';
    $(".bigandsmall").not(current).hide();
    $(current).show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="pilihWarna" name="fgdfd" style="background:none;">
  <option>satu</option>
  <option>dua</option>
  <option>tiga</option>
  <option>empat</option>
</select>    

<div class="something">
  <div data-key="satu" class="bigandsmall">
    <p>satu</p><img src="image/Chrysanthemum.jpg" width="50px" /></div>

  <div data-key="dua" class="bigandsmall">
    <p>dua</p><img src="image/Desert.jpg"  width="50px"/></div>

  <div data-key="tiga" class="bigandsmall">
    <p>tiga</p><img src="image/Hydrangeas.jpg"  width="50px"/></div>

  <div data-key="empat" class="bigandsmall">
    <p>empat</p><img src="image/Jellyfish.jpg"  width="50px"/></div>
</div>
```

But if you did that, you'd probably be doing it because you wanted these not to be unique, and so you'd probably need to work within some container.

Comment: how'd you use the change function with the code above?

Comment: @alisa: It depends on what you want it to do. If your goal is to have the `select` control which of those divs is shown, hiding all others, I'd put a `value` on the option, use `$(this).val()` in the callback to get it, and either use that as an `id` on the `.bigandsmall` divs or a `data-xyz` attribute. Then I'd hide all `.bigandsmall` that weren't a match for the value, and show the one that was.

Comment: @alisa: I've updated to show two possible ways above.